# Number increase Jquery Animation stop at random number sometimes.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
const ratingcount = document.querySelectorAll('.ratingcount');
const totalratingcounter = ratingcount.length;

var stopNow = totalratingcounter

countEach()
$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
      countEach()
})

function countEach() {
    $('.ratingcount').each(function() {
        if (showOnScreen(this) && $(this).attr('show') != 'false' && stopNow != 0) {
            //console.log($(this).text())
            //console.log($(this).attr('show'))
            $(this).attr('show', 'false')
            numberAnimate(this)
            stopNow = stopNow - 1;
        }/* else if (!showOnScreen(this)) {
            $(this).attr('show', 'true')
        }*/
    })
}

function showOnScreen(target) {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(target).offset().top)
      return true;
    else
        return false;
}

function numberAnimate(target) {
    var $this = $(target);
    jQuery({
        Counter: 0
    }).animate({
        Counter: $this.text()
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function() {
            $this.text(this.Counter.toFixed(1));
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span class="ratingcount">7.4</span>
<span class="ratingcount">7.4</span>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>


<span class="ratingcount">7.4</span>


<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>


<span class="ratingcount">7.4</span>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h38cq9ky/)

**Code Features:**

1. It increase the number animation from 0 to given number in 1 second.
2. If the number is on screen, while loading the page, it do the animation
3. If the number is not on screen, while loading the page, it do the animation on scroll
4. All numbers do the animation only 1 time.

Problem: Sometimes, some numbers stop at random number (below the original number). The script do not work properly. I do not know, why it happens (maybe bcz of slow internet, or something else).

How can I optimize the code and fix the problem?

Comment: Tried several times, don't found any issue.

Comment: Bro, I am not lying. You just tried with only this code. My original page has 5-6 more Jquery code's + PHP code that takes 1 sec to execute, total 800 lines